# How to create an iOS Time Picker programmatically?

Tags: ios, datetime, storyboard, timepicker, custom-datetimepicker

I have a tiny little problem.

I'd like to implement the time picker like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ja3.png]

This screen grab is from iOS 6's day notifications of DO NOT DISTURB

My question is how to do it ?

Any ideas ????

Are there any tutorials/resources online that you folks could suggest as how to do this ?

[edited] I should have mentioned that this for an iPhone not an iPad....

Thanks.

Comment: Create a custom view add the picker as it's subview, present it using popover.

Comment: I changed the tutorial link on my answer to a better one. It should now point exactly to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I found this popover solution -> https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

That created the popover I wanted, then added this bit of code to the

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method


    //  place inside a temporary view controller and add to popover

        UIViewController *viewCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    //    PopOverViewController *viewCon = [[PopOverViewController alloc] init];

        UIDatePicker *timePick;
        timePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 0, 0)];
        timePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeTime;

        [viewCon.view addSubview:timePick];

    //    viewCon.view = label;

        viewCon.contentSizeForViewInPopover = timePick.bounds.size ; // Set the content size

        popover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewCon];


        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 120)
                                inView:self.view
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                              animated:YES];
```

The only problem now is resizing the picker to the width that I want....other than that, it works!

The solutions that were presented will only work for an iPad not an iPhone....

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just create another view controller with the Time/DatePicker and whatever else you want in it. Use a modal Popover segue connected to your button and use the fixed size option to set the correct size that you want.

Good example [here](http://www.verious.com/article/mixing-popover-controllers-with-modal-view-controllers-1623719/).

Let me know if you need more data.

Comment: Thanks Jak!  Hmmm, I should modify my post to include that this is for iPhone and not iPad...would this same idea work with the iPhone ?

Comment: @MagicMiles Absolutely! The dimensions for the popover that are in the tutorial might be a little big, but you can change those. Just play with the CGSizeMake(400, 400) and change the numbers around until it looks good.

Comment: @MagicMiles. Did this answer your question? Do you need more help?

Comment: Hmmm @CaptJak, I do.  Couple of things I'm not clear on how to do....which this solution relies on you knowing...which I am clueless about implementing.

Comment: @MagicMiles What specifically? Without knowing, all I can do is give you [another tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/presenting-a-popover-in-ipad/)

Comment: Post at the link and I'll explain from there....simpler.
-> 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/106785544768557763311

Comment: Great! Glad you get it! (I was about to create a google account...)

Comment: I should point out that tutorial is for xibs and im using storyboards...slightly different interface requests....although I will say walking thru this wouldn't hurt!

Comment: @MagicMiles Just because you tagged storyboard, doesn't mean I read storyboard. Try putting it in your question next time if it is relevant information. Either way, it will still work for you.

Comment: Jak, your solution only covers HALF of the problem...Im ideally looking for a best pathway to recreating the time selector.  Any suggestions there ?

Comment: @MagicMiles Put the Time Selector in the new UIView that is being the popover. That way, when you click on the button that calls the popover, the time selector is in it, which will achieve the result that you wanted when you posted your question and should match the example that you gave.